# How to attach all the textures in my scene to blender

Tags: blend-files, linked-data, packed-data, library, packing

I created a project on my computer but as my computer has trouble rendering heavy scenes I send it to a render farm, so it can be faster.
The problem starts when the botaniq assets (the plugin I use to add vegetation to the scene) don't render the textures, but the asset meshes appear. When I went to look for the tree materials, they were linked and even after I activated the external data option, nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to ask the renderfarm you're using that question. We can only help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons.

Answer (score 0):

You mention using linked data.

Packing "Resources" will embed things like texture files, but not the linked blend files themselves.

To do this, use "Pack Libraries" in the same menu.